# Vuejs3 How to import from post list to detail view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I'm trying to try the post detail page in the post list, but I get an error properties of undefined on the detail view page. How do I load it?
What I was thinking of was getting that content from an empty array like a post list page. But that seems to be the wrong idea.

boardlist.vue

```
 
  <tr v-for="params in form" :key="params" @click="detailPage()">
        <td>{{params.title}}</td>
        <td>{{params.company}}</td>
        <td>{{params.company_url}}</td>
        <td>{{params.location}}</td>
        <td>{{params.description}}</td>
        <td>{{params.date_posted}}</td>
      </tr>

<script setup>
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { ref } from "vue";
const form = ref([]);
axios.get("api/jobs/all",{
  params: {
        title: "",
        company: "",
        company_url: "",
        location: "",
        description: "",
        date_posted: "",
  }
})
.then((res)=>{
  console.log(res.data)
  form.value = res.data;
})
</script>
```

boarddetail.vue

```
        <div v-for="params in form" :key="params" class="line-height">
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>title</div>
            <p>{{params.title}}``</p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>company</div>
            <p> {{params.company}}</p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>url</div>
            <p> {{params.company_url}}</p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>location</div>
            <p>{{params.location}}</p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>content</div>
            <div class="write_widt"><p>{{params.description}}</p></div>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="display_f">
            <div>date</div>
            <p>{{params.date_posted}}</p>
          </div>
       </div>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import axios from 'axios';
const form = ref([]);
axios.get("api/jobs/get/{id}",{
  params: {
        title: "",
        company: "",
        company_url: "",
        location: "",
        description: "",
        date_posted: "",
  }
})
.then((res)=>{
  console.log(res.data)
  form.value = res.data;
})
</script>
```

router

```
  {
    path: '/BoardDetail',
    name: 'BoardDetail',
    component: ToBoardDetail,
    props:true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined error should be come from the missing axios imports.

Comment: Is the wrong way to insert the Axios param data ""?

Comment: Missing axios import, e.g. import axios from 'axios'

Comment: Axios import is in use